# Why do test images for tod_detecting contain fiducial markers?

Tags: ros, tod-detecting

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why do the test images in http://vault.willowgarage.com/wgdata1/vol1/tod_kinect_bags/test/
contain fiducial markers? In order that they might also be used as training images for tod_detecting?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9605/why-do-test-images-for-tod_detecting-contain-fiducial-markers?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having fiducial markers on the test images lets one recover pose from those test images. We can use these pose estimates as ground truth to compare the performance of an object & pose detector. See also http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/SolutionsInPerceptionChallenge.

---

Originally posted by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) with karma: 960 on 2011-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3